# How to use stdin, stdout and stderr streams after attaching to a container using Docker api?

Tags: java, api, nginx, docker, stream

I am trying to attach to a container using the api given https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.22/

I have a docker-hub nginx image based container executing. I can send a request to attach to it, with the flags for stderr, stdin and stdout saved. My objective to use them interactively.

I am unable to figure out how to use the streams using java, the process of sending a command and reading the output.

I am using Docker version 1.10.1. Api v1.22. The operating system being used is Ubuntu 14.04. The application uses JDK 1.8.

I am focusing on using the attach command through an api call, like
http://localhost:4243/containers/container_id/attach?stdin=1&stdout=1
(4243 is where Docker listens for commands) and stdin and stdout flags are used to enable the streams. The documentation has the flag detail. After making the call, I want to "interact" with my container. which is possible according to the api documentation, however I am a little unclear on how to do so.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: After the request is sent should I just write to stdin and try and read stdout and stderr?

Comment: Yes. Your question is unclear though. Could you give more details, and specially the commands you are using, the environment (OS at least) you are in?

Comment: I updated the question. Please let me know if anything seems amiss.

Comment: Yup, all the commands you execute are still missing. Did you try `docker attach <container_ID>` or `docker exec -it`? You want to use the API from a Java app? How is this app performing the API call? Did you check the `docker-attach` source code (as you want to perform the same task)?

Comment: Auzias, Yes those are commands you can call from the terminal. I am trying to use the API from a Java application. I noticed that you can talk to a container interactively, according to the source code, so I am hoping attach can give me the same result as giving me exec -it <container> bash.

Answer (score 3):

You may use one of the libraries which allow you to interact with docker from Java program. Two possible alternatives are [docker-client](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client) and [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java). Docker-client has some problems attaching stdin, which are listed in [issue#156](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client/issues/156). There's a [known work-around](http://git.eclipse.org/c/linuxtools/org.eclipse.linuxtools.git/tree/containers/org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.core/src/org/eclipse/linuxtools/internal/docker/core/HttpHijackWorkaround.java?id=d2ebb42a239e3db61b13ea2b5d1df291e729d710) to fix this using some dirty reflection (it really works for me). So to launch the interactive application within the existing container with given `id`, use:

```
DockerClient dockerClient = DefaultDockerClient.builder()
      .uri( dockerURI )
      .readTimeoutMillis( Long.MAX_VALUE ) // without this interactive session may disconnect
      .build(); // use other config options if appropriate

String execId = dockerClient.execCreate(id, new String[] {"/bin/bash"}, 
    ExecCreateParam.attachStdin(), ExecCreateParam.attachStdout(),
    ExecCreateParam.attachStderr(), ExecCreateParam.tty() );
LogStream ls = dockerClient.execStart( execId );
```

Now use `ls.attach(stdout, stderr)` to redirect application stdout, stderr to your own `OutputStream` objects in separate thread. To write into stdin, use the trick linked above to get the `WritableByteChannel` and write into it whatever you want.

The docker-java library seems to have similar stdin issue solved (see [issue#253](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/issues/253)), though I never used docker-java.

Comment: I am going through the code. I am trying to implement my code for the following scenario - we can start and connect to a bash program using exec -it through the command line. I want to be able to do that using the api, and I found that attach fits the requirement the best. Thoughts?

Comment: @AdityaPan, I added more details how to use docker-client for interactive bash session. This perfectly works for me. Probably docker-java is better, you may try it as well (we just already started to use docker-client and don't want to migrate).

Comment: I will try it out and update on my findings soon. Thanks for your help @Tagir Valeev !